# change directory permission (chmod) in php

Tags: php, linux, apache, chmod

I have googled but I can't seem to get my script to work.

this is my code

```
if (is_dir("tmp")) {
    if (substr(sprintf("%o", fileperms("tmp")), -4) == "0777") {
        echo "good";
    } else {
        echo "going to chmod the tmp folder to 777";
        if (!chmod("tmp", octdec(0777))) { // tried chmod("tmp, 0777) too
                echo "Oops, I couldn't chmod the /setup/tmp directory, please do this manually";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "we'll make the folder";
}
```

I can't seem to get the chmod to work, i read somewhere that if register globals was off then this wouldn't work(i have that setting set to off).

I followed the PHP.net manual and some of the examples they provided there in the user comments, as well as some stack-overflow posts that i found relevant. but perhaps i need to tweak some php settings to get this to work?

Is there a way to get the chmod function to work without needing to change the PHP.ini?

Comment: Is the php user owner of the tmp dir or even in the group of that folder? If not, it cannot change the chmod of a folder.

Comment: its owner and part of the group

Comment: hm, is that a windows machine?

Comment: @Sn0opy: He mentions LAMP in a comment made on my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given us enough information to determine why [`chmod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) is failing. It could be that the web-server doesn't have sufficient privileges to alter directory permissions.

The owner of the web-server process should own the directory or be a member of the owning group. For example, if [root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser) owns *tmp*, and your web-server is running as the user 'apache', it will not be possible to modify the directory's permissions from PHP.

I believe the settings you mention in *php.ini* are for debugging, not magically 'fixing' `chmod`. Try prepending the following lines of code to your PHP script and you should get more useful debug output:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL)
```

Comment: ah, this says that Operation no permitted for the chmod. I will probably need to see if the scripts are running with owner user and permissions then. I thought they where since I set up the LAMP server myself. Any suggestion? I really do have the apache running as the same owner as the user i am logged in with.

Comment: If you don't have permissions to use `chmod` on *tmp*, but you have root terminal access on the server, then you can use `ps aux | grep http` to view Apache's process details and find the user. Once you know the user that Apache is running under, you can take directory ownership of *tmp* with `sudo chown -R webProcessUser /path/to/tmp`. If don't want to change the directory owner, and you know the user running Apache belongs to some group, you can change the group owner instead: `sudo chown -R currentOwner:newGroup /path/to/tmp`

Answer (score 0):

Represent like this:-

```
chmod("tmp", 0777);
```

Comment: i tried that as well, my current version that I posted was from an example from the php.net chmod user comments

Answer (score 0):

The user that is running the php daemon or web server daemon must have write access to the directory you are trying to chmod. In my case, www-data is the user that is running php and any commands that php is trying to run, it will be run as the www-data user.

If you create a directory using the php mkdir function, you will notice that the owner of the directory is who ever is running the php or webserver daemon. And any directory that was created by php, php will be able to chmod, chown, do anything to it because it is the owner.

You can either

1. chown the directory so that the owner is the php user
2. set writing privileges for the group and set the group to the same group as the php user
3. do something like giving sudo privileges to the php user which is not recommended btw.